# RPC Server Procedure Not Calling Printf

Tags: c, rpc

I've got a super simple RPC program I'm trying to implement, and I'm stuck at the beginning. Here is the .x:

```
struct intpair{
     int a;
     int b;
     string word<>;
};

program ADD_PROG{
      version ADD_VERS{
              int ADD(intpair)=1;
         } = 1;
} = 0x20000005;
```

Here is the server routine in add_server.c:

```
/** This is sample code generated by rpcgen
 *  These are only templates and you can use them 
 *  as a guideline for developing your own functions.
 */

#include "add.h"
 int * add_1_svc(intpair *argp, struct svc_req *rqstp)
    {
     static int  result;
/*
* insert server code here
*/
     printf("add function called here we are\n");
     printf("parameters");

     return &result;
```

}

For some reason I cannot get the server to actually print "parameters". Does anybody know what is going wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: `printf("parameters");` --> `printf("parameters\n");`

Comment: No, string word<> is rpc language. Thanks, the new line did it. Do you know why that is?

Comment: Take a look here: [why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

Comment: The rest of it is C. It compiles into C, but the add.x is whatever language rpcgen compiles from. Do you have a better tag?

Comment: @LPs is there an automatic flush when you call printf() from a programming running in a bash shell or something?

Comment: @nbk: Either set the stream unbuffered or `fflush` it

Comment: @Olaf Yeah, I got that. I'm just wondering why I don't have to flush the stream when I'm compiling and executing on my home machine through a bash shell...

Comment: That is not related to the shell. There have been enough q&a about this here and elsewhere. How about doing some research on this subject.

Comment: Different platforms?..

Comment: not needed to warn OP.

Comment: You should have taken the [tour]! The owner of the posting (answer/question) automatically gets a notification.